# Do people actually ever say みょうにち?

Tags: word-choice, words, readings, spoken-language, wago-and-kango

I've heard people using あした (the common one) and あす (rather uncommon) to refer to "tomorrow".

I was wondering does anyone actually uses the reading みょうにち ?

Comment: Wow, that sounds so cool.  You should use it.

Comment: I don't think this really answers your question in the spirit that you asked it, but my answer is "yes, some people do." Because I'm now using it. Because I saw this question. `:)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have heard it used in formal (e.g. business) contexts. I have never heard it used in casual conversations among friends or family.

This is what you might expect, because Sino-Japanese words like みょうにち do tend to have a more formal feel than native Japanese words like あした or あす, when they exist alongside each other with similar meanings.

Answer (score 7):

In some parts of Tohoku, the greeting "おやすみなさい" or "また明日" is said "おみょうにづ", with is a deformation from "おみょうにち".  Even though it refers to the *next* day, I think that "お" is the same one as in "お早う".

I can't remember whether "あした" is casually said "みょうにづ" though…

Comment: Great info.  Thank you.  Is it just Tohoku?

Comment: I don't know any other dialect, so I can't answer that.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes old people do. I don't know why, but maybe they feel uncomfortable with 熟字訓読み as in あした or あす, where the portion of the pronunciation of a word does not match each kanji character.