# Can さくじつ and きのう be used the same way?

Tags: word-choice, words, usage, wago-and-kango

Can さくじつ and きのう be used the same way? I know the terms mean yesterday. Thank you!

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2221/9831 See also: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/13777/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/18365/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/28952/9831

Comment: it seems to be related to the significance of the word, maybe an important event...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on the context.

さくじつ and きのう both mean yesterday (and the same Kanji 昨日 is used for the words). A major difference in their usage is that さくじつ is almost always used in a **formal** context (written and spoken), while きのう is often used **both** in formal and informal contexts (written and spoken): Using さくじつ in a casual conversation seems weird. You can hear きのう not only in a casual conversation but also in the news.